# Flow Type casting

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype

I am coming from Typescript and trying Flow Type right now.

In TypeScript i can do this.

```
interface x {
    name: string;
}

let y = <x> {
    name: "John Doe"
};
```

**How can i do this with flow type?**

On [Flow - Announcing Typecasts](https://flowtype.org/blog/2015/02/18/Typecasts.html) i saw that flow's syntax for casts is e.g.

```
(myVar: myType)
```

but

```
let y = {
    name: "John Doe"
}: x;
```

does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parentheses are mandatory. Use

```
let y = ({
    name: "John Doe"
}: x);
```